# Trying to upload a photo using Tkinter photoimage

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been trying to load a photo onto a Tkinter canvas but I keep failing to do so. The message I get is: `TclError: couldn't open "C:\Jules\...\photo_files•0651442_51c04521d6.gif": no such file or directory.`

I am using Python 2.7.
Here is my code.

```
import Tkinter
topthree = Tkinter.Tk()

canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(topthree, height=800, width= 800)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
photo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "C:\Jules\...\6250651442_51c04521d6.gif")
im = canvas.create_image(0,0, image=photo)

canvas.pack()
topthree.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `r` before the file name:

```
photo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Jules\...\6250651442_51c04521d6.gif")
```

This is because the backslash interprets the next char as a control char, and this can cause some chars to disappear. For example, `\n` becomes a new line and the `n` goes away...

Writing `r` before the string cancels control characters. (`r` stands for raw string)

Comment: even better: use the forward slash instead of the backslash.